# SQL Server many-to-many design recommendation

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, database-design, many-to-many

I have a SQL Server database with two table : Users and Achievements. My users can have multiple achievements so it a many-to-many relation.

At school we learned to create an associative table for that sort of relation. That mean creating a table with a UserID and an AchivementID. But if I have 500 users and 50 achievements that could lead to 25 000 row.

As an alternative, I could add a binary field to my Users table. For example, if that field contained 10010 that would mean that this user unlocked the first and the fourth achievements.

Is their other way ? And which one should I use.

Comment: Do these Achievements need to be completed or unlocked in consecutive order?

Comment: use associative tables, if each user has 50 achievements then it will be 25000 row. Will each user have 50 ? i don't thinks so. And other what do you want to achieve, reduce the disk space or efficient queries?

Comment: Use the third table, there are 25000 possible relations and i doubt each user will earn every achivement and even if they do it is much more flexible solution.

Comment: @Berkay and @rebus : It was just an example, I'm afraid it will grow to big to fast.

Comment: Yeah, sure - it might get lots of rows. Just put an index (probably the clustered index / primary key) on the two columns, and you should be just fine. SQL Server can handle 100 of millions of rows - no problem. 25'000 is **NOTHING AT ALL!**  Even with 5000 users at 100 achievements each, that's only 500'000 rows - at 8 bytes each, that's 4 MB of data.... SQL Server will most likely cache that in memory all the time.....

Comment: Don't over-optimize ahead of time and spend a lot of time and effort in a place that's really not a problem and not worth sweating over.

Comment: don't worry, sql handles the efficiency of queries by indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternative way isn't a very good approach at all.  Not only is it not queryable (how many people unlocked achievement #10?), but it means nothing.  Plus, what are you going to do if you add 5 more achievements?  Update all the previous users to add "00000" to the end of their "achievements" column?

There is nothing wrong with the associative table as long as you index it properly.  Using that approach the data is infinitly queryable and - perhaps more importantly - makes sense!